# Create a MIN IFS function in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010, does not have `MINIF` built it.

To  get around this I could use an array forumla.

**Sample Data.**

```
Field 1 Field 2 Score
B       1       1
A       1       2
A       0       3
A       0       4
B       1       5
```

If i wanted the Min Score if Field 1 equaled A i would use:

```
{=MIN(IF(A2:A6="A",C2:C6,""))}
```

This works fine for a MIN IF,

But say i want the min score if `field 1` equals `A` AND `field 2` equals `1`.

When i introduce AND, to represent two conditions it fails. i.e MINIFS

```
{=MIN(IF(AND(A2:A6="A",B2:B6=1),C2:C6,""))}
```

Does anyone have a work around ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `AND` with array formula because the result is a single value rather than an array - try like this which uses * to simulate `AND`

`=MIN(IF((A2:A6="A")*(B2:B6=1),C2:C6))`

or with multiple IFs like this:

`=MIN(IF(A2:A6="A",IF(B2:B6=1,C2:C6)))`

both confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Two great answers.  I am partial to formulas where arrays of logical values are multiplied.  But Skoddie snuck in at t-7 and he's a nubie, so I'm going to give him a vote.  :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch no problem, I'm never quite sure which way is preferable but with * to multiply you can easily switch to + for OR which might give it the edge....

Answer (score 2):

## Nested IF Statements

As you've noticed, the AND function does not support arrays, but you can accomplish the outcome you're looking for by nesting IF statements.

The formula I used on your data is as follows:

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A6="A",IF(B2:B6=1,C2:C6)))
```

*This is an array formula, press ctrl+shift+enter to use*

This works due to the way Excel processes boolean data internally, if the FALSE case is not specified, it will return 0.

Comment: Hah beaten by 7 minutes. I had also considered boolean arithmetic, however I ultimately decided to omit it as it's workings are less clear to a user unfamiliar with how Excel manages data internally. Listing both was a good move on @barry houdini's end!

Answer (score 1):

*You can use a combination of INDEX and MATCH to find the Minimum value where exercise is based on multiple Criteria. This Formula can be used for Single Criteria also.*

```
{=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(1,IF(A2:A6="A",IF(B2:B6=1,1)),0))}
```

Note, it's an Array Formula so finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.